# Starting hubs more than once

Tags: signalr

Let's say my global.js does this (included in every page):

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    doSomething1();
});
```

and a developer does this on a custom page

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    doSomething2();
});
```

causing that both scripts are running.

1. Is this allowed or would that cause any problems?

If it's allowed:

2. script 1 starts, and done is started before as script 2 starts. Will doSomething2() be skipped?
3. script 1 starts, script 2 starts. done of script 1 starts. Will doSomething2() be skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. won't cause any problems

For number 1, 2 and 3:

Try something like a [pubsub](https://github.com/phiggins42/bloody-jquery-plugins/blob/master/pubsub.js) library. In your global.js do a publish and let your developers subscribe to that instead.